# Create a Pandas Holiday/Offset object that spans multiple days

Tags: python, pandas

Given the below (working) Pandas calendar that sets a sequential set of days between Dec 22-30 as Holidays, is there a way to write this so that a **range** of dates can be set, **instead of listing out each day individually**?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tseries.holiday as h

class CodeFreezeCalendar(h.AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        h.Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=h.nearest_workday),
        h.USThanksgivingDay,
        h.Holiday('Dec 22', month=12, day=22),
        h.Holiday('Dec 23', month=12, day=23),
        h.Holiday('Dec 24', month=12, day=24),
        h.Holiday('Dec 25', month=12, day=25),
        h.Holiday('Dec 26', month=12, day=26),
        h.Holiday('Dec 27', month=12, day=27),
        h.Holiday('Dec 28', month=12, day=28),
        h.Holiday('Dec 29', month=12, day=29),
        h.Holiday('Dec 30', month=12, day=30)
        )
    ]
```

I didn't see a way to have [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-dateoffset) handle an inclusive range of dates, so I don't think it can be used here. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tseries.holiday as h

class CodeFreezeCalendar(h.AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        h.Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=h.nearest_workday),
        h.USThanksgivingDay,
        *[h.Holiday(f'Dec {d}', month=12, day=d) for d in range(22,31)]
             ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. What is that `*[]` sytax/format called? I would like to read about it.

Comment: Search "python asterisk operator"

Answer (score 0):

If you use a for loop for the set days, 22-30, you can make a list and just add new years eve and thanksgiving after like this. Then add the dates for nye and thanksgiving manually.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tseries.holiday as h

class CodeFreezeCalendar(h.AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = []
    start = 22
    end = 30
    for i in range(start,end+1):
        rules.append(h.Holiday(f'Dec {i}', month=12, day=i),)

    rules += [
        h.Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=h.nearest_workday),
        h.USThanksgivingDay,
    ]
```